# Why is this VBA code ignoring the 0' in my excel cells?

Tags: excel, vba

Full disclosure, I am not a coder. I can read and manipulate code but I never write from scratch.

I am creating an excel stocktake sheet that outputs a txt file to import into our companies stock system.

I have a piece of VBA code that takes Data from Column A and Column C and writes it to a .txt file.
The code looks for data in Column C and if it has a value of 0 or greater it should write the value in Column A separated by a , with the Value in Column C.

Some cells in column c have 0 values and some have formulas to calculate the correct values.

Currently the code works except that it ignores cells with 0 values and also it doesn't stop at the last cell with data in column C, it gives the second last line as 0,0 in the txt file.

```
Private Sub Select_Visible_Rows()
    On Error Resume Next ' Enable error handling

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Dim a As Long, i As Long
    Dim b As Long, c As Long
    Dim wsOrder As Worksheet, wsImport As Worksheet
    Dim outputFile As Object

    Set wsOrder = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Order Sheet")
    Set wsImport = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("IQ Import Sheet")

    a = wsOrder.Cells(wsOrder.Rows.Count, 1).End(x1Up).Row

    ' Create a FileSystemObject to work with files
    Set outputFile = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").CreateTextFile("C:\Stocktake\Stocktake " & Format(Now(), "DD-MM-YYYY") & ".txt")

Dim lastRow As Long
lastRow = wsOrder.Cells(wsOrder.Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 3 To lastRow
    If IsNumeric(wsOrder.Cells(i, 3).Value) And wsOrder.Cells(i, 3).Value >= 0 Then
        ' Check if Column A is not blank
        If Len(Trim(wsOrder.Cells(i, 1).Text)) > 0 And Not (wsOrder.Cells(i, 3).Text Like "=*") Then
            ' Write data to the text file, separated by commas
            outputFile.Write wsOrder.Cells(i, 1).Value & ","
            outputFile.WriteLine wsOrder.Cells(i, 3).Value
        End If
    End If
Next


    ' Close the text file
    outputFile.Close

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    ActiveWorkbook.Save

    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("IQ Import Sheet").Cells(1, 1).Select

    On Error GoTo 0 ' Disable error handling
End Sub
```

I have tried a lot of combinations and tried to use chatGPT to assist but I cant seem to get it right.

I just need the txt file to give me an output of data in column A (product code) comma separated with with the value in column C (Qty). Even if the value is  0

Comment: First thing you should do when encountering unwanted behaviour is to remove `On Error Resume Next` as you don't get any error messages that could cause this. Next is to start debugging, you can set watches to check when cells(i, 3) = 0 to interrupt the code so you can check the values of the different variables and step through one statement at a time.

Comment: One mistake would already be `x1Up` at `a = wsOrder.Cells(wsOrder.Rows.Count, 1).End(x1Up).Row`. That should be `xlUp` (the letter l not the number 1). You'd instantly see this with Option Explicit see [this](https://excelchamps.com/vba/option-explicit/) (but this shouldn't have caused the issue at hand since you're not using a)

Comment: `Not (wsOrder.Cells(i, 3).Text Like "=*")`
What is it for?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply.
The "=*" was one of the attempts to ignore blank cells with a formula in them. The end results sometime gave me outputs for blank cells with formulas

Comment: If so, you should use `Formula`, not `Text`: 
`Not (wsOrder.Cells(i, 3).Formula Like "=*")` because `.Text` tells us what is visible inside a cell.

Comment: Then every cell with a formula would be skipped due to the wildcard @MGonet

Comment: `Dim lastRow As Long
lastRow = wsOrder.Cells(wsOrder.Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 3 To lastRow
    If IsNumeric(wsOrder.Cells(i, 3).Value) And Not IsEmpty(wsOrder.Cells(i, 3).Value) Then
        ' Check if Column A is not blank
        If Len(Trim(wsOrder.Cells(i, 1).Text)) >= 0 And Not (wsOrder.Cells(i, 3).HasFormula) Then
            ' Write data to the text file, separated by commas
            outputFile.Write wsOrder.Cells(i, 1).Value & ","
            outputFile.WriteLine wsOrder.Cells(i, 3).Value
        End If
    End If
Next`

Comment: I updated the loop to this but i and LastRow values are out of context. I dont know what that means.
Sorry cant seem to get the code format right in the comments

Comment: @Notus_Panda It was only a suggestion. I don't know your data. You can add additonal condition for `Text` or for `Value` `=""` or `<>""` whatever you need.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following changes:

- On Error Resume Next is gone because it shouldn't be used unless you're trying to catch a known error you actually want to skip
- Placed the A & C-value in variables and checked if its length is > 0 (to avoid the empty values)
- Removed the `Not (wsOrder.Cells(i, 3).Text Like "=*")` because of the previous point
- Used `ThisWorkbook.Save` instead of `ActiveWorkbook.Save` since I'm not seeing any other workbook being used and placed it after Activating the Import sheet and selecting A1 there.
- Removed a and its later line, b and c since they were all not being used

Let me know if I missed something :)

```
Private Sub Select_Visible_Rows()

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Dim i As Long
    Dim wsOrder As Worksheet, wsImport As Worksheet
    Dim outputFile As Object

    Set wsOrder = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Order Sheet")
    Set wsImport = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("IQ Import Sheet")

    ' Create a FileSystemObject to work with files
    Set outputFile = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").CreateTextFile("Q:\Aankoop\Werkfiles Excel\Steven\Test\Stocktake " & Format(Now(), "DD-MM-YYYY") & ".txt")

    Dim lastRow As Long
    lastRow = wsOrder.Cells(wsOrder.Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row
    Dim cVal, aVal
    
    For i = 3 To lastRow
        cVal = wsOrder.Cells(i, 3).Value
        aVal = wsOrder.Cells(i, 1).Value
        If Not IsError(cVal) Then
            If Len(cVal) > 0 And IsNumeric(cVal) And cVal >= 0 Then
                ' Check if Column A is not blank
                If Len(Trim(aVal)) > 0 Then
                    ' Write data to the text file, separated by commas
                    outputFile.Write aVal & ","
                    outputFile.WriteLine cVal
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Next


    ' Close the text file
    outputFile.Close

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    wsImport.Activate
    wsImport.Cells(1, 1).Select
    ThisWorkbook.Save
End Sub
```

IsNumeric will see an empty cell as 0 btw, so you were going into those Ifs regardless. Checking its length is needed because of that.

Comment: Hi #Notus_Panda
Why would there be a type mismatch in the for loop. I tried a couple of alterations but cant seem to get it to work. `If Len(cVal) > 0 And IsNumeric(cVal) And Val(cVal) >= 0 Then` . I changed the last cVal to Val(cVal) but it still gives me the error

Comment: Try the updated code, you likely have an error code in your sheet which throws an error already at `Len(cVal) > 0`

Answer (score 0):

In short, iterate through a range a cells, check their contents, and if they pass all checks, write their values to a file.

> Currently the code works except that it ignores cells with 0 values and also it doesn't stop at the last cell with data in column C, it gives the second last line as 0,0 in the txt file.

I can't explain what's causing this exactly, but I can give some meta advice.  When performing a bunch of comparisons, try to keep them as separate and clean as possible.  You are using a few `AND`s to combine comparisons, which clutter the code.  You're also performing comparisons within other comparisons, which is going to make it harder to walk through them and figure out why they're not working.

Here's the code, and we'll walk through it after:

```
Private Sub Rewrite_Select_Visible_Rows()
    
    Dim wsOrder As Worksheet
    Set wsOrder = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Order Sheet")

    ' Create the output file
    Dim outputFile As Object
    Set outputFile = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").CreateTextFile("C:\Stocktake\Stocktake " & Format(Now(), "DD-MM-YYYY") & ".txt")
    
    Dim lastRow As Long
    lastRow = wsOrder.Cells(wsOrder.Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row

    Dim i As Long, firstColumnItem As String, thirdColumnItem As String
    For i = 3 To lastRow
        
        ' Store looped items - easier to read code
        firstColumnItem = wsOrder.Cells(i, 1).Value
        thirdColumnItem = wsOrder.Cells(i, 3).Value
        
        ' Use early exit approach
        ' Does not handle spaces
        If firstColumnItem = "" Then GoTo ContinueLoop            ' first column may not be empty
        If Not IsNumeric(thirdColumnItem) Then GoTo ContinueLoop  ' first column must have a number
        If Not thirdColumnItem >= 0 Then GoTo ContinueLoop        ' third column may not be less than 0
        
        ' Data passed all checks
        outputFile.Write firstColumnItem & "," & thirdColumnItem & vbNewLine
        
ContinueLoop:
    Next i

    outputFile.Close
        
End Sub
```

First, I've cleared away all variables that aren't strictly required by your code, such as `a` and `wsImport`.  This will make debugging easier.

Second, I've removed `On Error Resume Next` and `Application.ScreenUpdating = False` lines.  We're trying to determine why the code isn't working, so hiding errors and not updating the screen isn't helpful.

The code, in principle, is the same as you've shown.  The only real change shows up when we do the comparisons.  In the loop, we'll take the early exit approach, meaning that if a check fails, we move on to the next iteration of the loop.  This way, each check can be written and performed independently of the others.  We check that thr item in column one isn't empty, then we check that the item in column one is a number, then we check that the item in column three is greater than zero.  If all those checks are passed, the data is written to the file.  Otherwise, we go to the `ContinueLoop` line, which just starts the next iteration of the `For` loop.

Comment: The real change in your case is passing the value to a string variable causing empty values to not be seen as 0 with `IsNumeric`. Other than not catching error values (type mismatch when assigning the value to the variable), this works as well @OP

Comment: I figured out what the problem is. Excel can't see the difference between a blank cell and a cell containing a 0. Both shows up as 0.
Is there a work around for this issue? I have been searching everywhere but can't seem to find the solution that works

Comment: @StephanJacobs The code `ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(1,1).Value` will return an empty string if there are no contents in cell A1, and it will return a 0 if there is a 0 in the cell A1.  If you are still running in to this issue, create a new simplified code to test this, and if that still fails, ask a new question.